# Generic function for jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got following solution to prevent of multiple clicks (respect only the first one and ignore the rest):

```
preventMultiClick = function() {
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).bind("click", function() {
        return false;
    });
};
preventMultiSubmit = function() {
    $(this).unbind("submit");
    $(this).bind("submit", function() {
        return false;
    });
};
$("a").one("click", preventMultiClick);
$("#user").one("submit", preventMultiSubmit);
```

That solution for me is not elegant I think should be. So I tried upgrade it to following one:

```
preventMultiClick = function(event) {
    $(this).unbind(event);
    $(this).bind(event, function() {
        return false;
    });
};
$("a").one("click", preventMultiClick("click"));
$("#user").one("submit", preventMultiClick("submit"));
```

and that solution doesn't work. Could somebody explain why or tell me how the function respecting event given as function argument should be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are calling the function when you are binding the handler, `event` object is passed to your handler, also `event` is an object, you should use it's `type` property.

```
var preventMultiClick = function(event) {
    $(this).unbind(event.type);
    $(this).bind(event.type, function() {
        return false;
    });
};

$("a").one("click", preventMultiClick);
$("#user").one("submit", preventMultiClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing in an undefined variable rather than the function reference. Instead I would do something like this.

```
preventMultiClick = function(event) {
    $(this).unbind(event.type);
    $(this).bind(event.type, function() {
        return false;
    });
};

$('a').one('click', preventMultiClick);
$('#user').one('submit', preventMultiClick);
```

Each event contains it's type.